# How to interpret the Grassmannian $G(\mathbb P, \mathbb P^m)$ as a moduli space of stable maps

Tags: moduli-spaces, grassmannians

> **Definition** Let $X$ be a nonsingular (complex)projective variety. A morphism $f$ from a $n$-pointed nodal curve $\Sigma$ to $X$ is a **stable map** if every genus 0 contracted component of $\Sigma$ (where contracted means mapping to a point) has at least three special points, and every genus 1 contracted component has at least one special point. And denote by $\bar{\mathcal M}_{g,n} (X, \beta)$ the moduli space of stable maps from $n$-pointed genus $g$ nodal curves to $X$ representing the class $\beta\in H_2(M,\mathbb Z)$.

The Grassmannian $G(\mathbb P, \mathbb P^m) $ parametrize lines in $\mathbb P^m$. I have been told that $G(\mathbb P, \mathbb P^m) $ can be regarded as the moduli space $\bar{\mathcal M}_{0,0} (X, \beta)$ for some $\beta$ (I don't know too).

I find it hard to understand the precise interpretation of this. Please help, thanks!

Comment: @BenMcKay  Really? I copy the statement from a reference book.  I use $\bar{\mathcal M}_{0,0} (X, \beta)$, which means the number of marked points is $n=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I had it wrong. Your Grassmannian is a quotient of the moduli space of stable maps in the homology class $\beta$. Here $\beta$ is the homology class of a projective line in projective space. Any holomorphic map of the projective line to projective space which sends the homology class of the projective line to that of a line in projective space is a projective linear map to a line in projective space. However, you have to quotient by the automorphisms of the domain. If $m=1$, your moduli space is the projective general linear group, not compact, while your quotient is a point.

Comment: @BenMcKay Thank you for your answer. Would you mind further explaining why any holomorphic map of the projective line to projective space which sends the homology class of the projective line to that of a line in projective space is a projective linear map to a line in projective space?

Comment: If we take a projective hyperplane not containing our curve, it intersects it at a single point by homology count and because intersections of complex subvarieties of complementary dimension are positive. But then if we take two points of our curve, any hyperplane through those two points has two points of intersection, at least, so must contain the curve. Hence the curve lies in the intersection of all hyperplanes through any two of its points, i.e. lies in a line. So we can now reduce to the case when the projective space is a line, which should be straightforward.